# What is the default / maximum value for WEBJOBS_RESTART_TIME?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a continuous webjob and sometimes it can take a REALLY, REALLY long time to process (i.e. several days). I'm not interested in partitioning it into smaller chunks to get it done faster (by doing it more parallel). Having it run slow and steady is fine with me. I was looking at the documentation about webjobs [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs#configuration-settings) where it lists out all the settings but it doesn't specify the defaults or maximums for these values. I was curious if anybody knew.

Answer (score 1):

Since the docs say

> "**WEBJOBS_RESTART_TIME** - Timeout in seconds between when a continuous job's process goes down (for any reason) and the time we re-launch it again (Only for continuous jobs)."

it doesn't matter how long your process runs.

Please clarify your question as most part of it is irrelevant to what you're asking at the end.

If you want to know the min - I'd say try `0`. For max try `MAX_INT` (`2147483647`), that's 68 years. That should do it ;).

Comment: Please note that this setting is a delay between when your Job goes down and when the kudu site will restart it. This is NOT "how long will my job be allowed to run". A continuous WebJob is continuous. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "max run time" for a continuous WebJob. Note that, in practice, there aren't any assurances on how long a given instance of your Web App hosting the WebJob is going to exist, and thus your WebJob may restart anyway. It's always good design to have your continuous job idempotent; meaning it can be restarted many times, and pick back up where it left off.